# How to gracefully traverse a string in C to the end

Tags: c, string, null, traversal

I am working on a C function which must input a string and remove all the non-letter characters at the beginning only.  For example, if the input string was `"123 456 My dog has fleas."` then the output string must be: `"My dog has fleas."`

Here's what I have, which works on the above example:

```
int isALetter(char x){
   // Checks to see is x is an ASCII letter
   if(  ((int)x>=65 && (int)x<=90)  ||  ((int)x>=97 && (int)x<=122)  )
      return 0;      // TRUE
   return 1;         // FALSE
}
char* removeNonLettersAtBeginning(char* str){
   while( isALetter(str[0]) == 1  &&  &str[0] != NULL )
      str++;
   return str;
}
```

Here's what bugs me...  If the string has no letters at all, the code doesn't seem to work.  If I submit string `"          "` (no letters) then I get "`XDG_SESSION_ID=3818`".  I don't know what that string is, but I'm assuming its "garbage" in the system.

But my `removeNonLettersAtBeginning()` function should be returning a "" string, an empty string.  I can't figure out what the problem is, but I'm betting it lies here:

```
   while( isALetter(str[0]) == 1  &&  &str[0] != NULL )
```

The `"&str[0] != NULL"` part of that line is to ensure I don't run off the end of the string; I'm trying to check to see if I've hit the Null character which terminates the string.  Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `&str[0] != NULL` should come before `isALetter(str[0])`.  If `str == NULL` you're attempting to dereference it.

Comment: unrelated, but `if(  ((int)x>=65 && (int)x<=90)  ||  ((int)x>=97 && (int)x<=122)  )` --> `if(  (x>='A' && x<='Z')  ||  (x>='a' && x<='z')  )`

Comment: '&str[0] != NULL' is wrong. &str[0] == str so it will never be NULL. You should use 'str[0] != '\0'

Comment: @yano Good point. Don't use _magic numbers_.

Comment: 1. Include the header `<ctype.h>` and use the standard `isalpha()` function.  2. Use `str[0] != '\0'` instead of `&str[0] != NULL`.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt That's incorrect. `str` can be `NULL`.  `&str` would never be `NULL`.

Comment: `while( isALetter(*str) == 1  &&  *str != '\0' )`

Comment: @fiddlingBits of course it can, if NULL is passed to  `removeNonLettersAtBeginning()` but then `isALetter( str[0] )` is UB anyway. OP stated explicitely that this check should find the end of the string

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Okay, I thought the check was for a `NULL` pointer. Apologies.

Comment: @fiddlingBits no problem

Comment: @Olaf I don't quite understand. `char *str = "abcde"; if( str == &str[0] ) printf( "equal\n" ); else printf( "not equal\n" );` prints "equal" on different Linux systems,  solaris and aix. Both `str` and `&str[0]` are `char *`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt: Forget it. I somehow was completely off-track (I somehow had in mind comparing a `char (*)[]` and a `char *`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach.

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
void stripNonAlpha( char *str )
{
  size_t r = 0, w = 0; // read and write indices

  /**
   * Find the first alpha character in the string
   */
  while ( str[r] && !isalpha( str[r] ) )
    r++;

  /**
   * Shift remaining characters to the left, including the 0 terminator
   */
  while ( (str[w++] = str[r++] ) )
    ; //empty loop
}
```

Basically, this code searches for the first alphabetical character in the string; once found, that character and all following characters are copied over the initial part of the string.  For example, let's take the string `"123 test"`.  Initially, here's what everything looks like:

```
  r
  |
  v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|'1'|'2'|'3'|' '|'t'|'e'|'s'|'t'| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^
  |
  w
```

The first loop checks the value of the character at index `r`; while it's neither the end of the string nor an alpha character, advance `r`.  At the end of the loop, we have this:

```
                  r
                  |
                  v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|'1'|'2'|'3'|' '|'t'|'e'|'s'|'t'| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^
  |
  w
```

The second loop copies characters from `r` and writes them to `w` (up to and including the 0 terminator), like so:

```
                      r
                      |
                      v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|'t'|'2'|'3'|' '|'t'|'e'|'s'|'t'| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      ^
      |
      w
                          r
                          |
                          v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|'t'|'e'|'3'|' '|'t'|'e'|'s'|'t'| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
          ^
          |
          w
                              r
                              |
                              v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|'t'|'e'|'s'|' '|'t'|'e'|'s'|'t'| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
              ^
              |
              w
                                  r
                                  |
                                  v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|'t'|'e'|'s'|'t'|'t'|'e'|'s'|'t'| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                  ^
                  |
                  w
                                      r
                                      |
                                      v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|'t'|'e'|'s'|'t'| 0 |'e'|'s'|'t'| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                      ^
                      |
                      w
```

Some sample output:

```
$ ./stripper "123 345 this is a test"
before: "123 345 this is a test"
after:  "this is a test"

$ ./stripper "this is a test"
before: "this is a test"
after:  "this is a test"

$ ./stripper "          "
before: "          "
after:  ""

$ ./stripper "12345"
before: "12345"
after:  ""

$ ./stripper "12345 abc 23456"
before: "12345 abc 23456"
after:  "abc 23456"
```

Obviously, this operation is destructive - the input string is modified.  If you don't want that, you'll need to write to a different target string.  That should be easy enough to figure out, through.

Answer (score 2):

You check of null terminator is wrong, null terminator is `'\0'` not `NULL`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isALetter(char x){
   // Checks to see is x is an ASCII letter
   if( (x>='A' && x<='Z') || (x>='a' && x<='z') )
      return 0;      // TRUE
   return 1;         // FALSE
}
char* removeNonLettersAtBeginning(char* str){
   if (str != NULL)
   {
      while( isALetter(*str) == 1  &&  *str != '\0' )
         str++;
   }
   return str;
}

int main (void)
{
    char test_string[] = "        test\n";
    char *test_ptr = test_string;

    printf ("%s", test_ptr);

    test_ptr = removeNonLettersAtBeginning(test_ptr);

    printf ("%s", test_ptr);
}
```

As a side note, to make your code more readable, avoid using magic numbers like `65`, `90`.
You can, as shown, easily use chars to do so: `'A'`, `'Z'`...

Comment: I think the main problem was not the `NULL`, but the extra `&`.  (But, yes, `'\0'` is a much better null character constant.)

Comment: Strictly speaking, `x>='A' && x<='Z'` isn't the right solution, either, as it can fail on certain obscure, non-ASCII character sets.  Much better to use `isalpha()` from `<ctype.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

you write :

```
while( isALetter(str[0]) == 1  &&  &str[0] != NULL ) //error in str[0] 
      str++;                                         //it must be *str
```

here, you used char * str which will points to string that is to be tested.

As you said you want to remove all non-characters from string.
but, **you're using a char type of pointer in wrong way.**

error free code:

```
 while( isALetter(*str) == 1  &&  *str != '\0')  
          str++;
```

it should be work for u in favour :)

Comment: Why is that the 'wrong way'? Doesn't it look the same to the compiler?

Comment: yes, some older compilor like turbo still suffers .